# Past textual date to days (since) PHP

Tags: php, date, days

Hey guys,
how does one calculate the days past since a date like the one Twitter outputs in its API
eg:

> Mon Jul 12 00:27:26 +0000 2010

to XXX

Can we do it with [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Thanks guys,
Dex

Comment: Try this: [strptime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like that (where `$your_date` is the string you mentioned):

```
$diff = (time() - strtotime($your_date)) / (24*60*60);
```

In your case, when I did `echo $diff;` the output was (at the time I posted the answer):

```
321.85475694444
```

See more details for [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), [`time()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) and [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Hope this helped you.

Answer (score 1):

*Compatibility note: works only for PHP >= 5.3.0*

Providing that the date format does not change, you can reverse the process (i.e. reverse timestamp -> string (on Twitters servers) to timestamp) using the exact date format. Using the table on the manual page of [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

```
<?php
$str = 'Mon Jul 12 00:27:26 +0000 2010';
$oDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('D M d H:i:s T Y', $str);
$unix_timestamp = $oDateTime->getTimestamp();
echo $unix_timestamp;
?>
```

Beware: On my machine, `date('d-m-Y H:i:s', $unix_timestamp)` differs two hours, the machines timezone is GMT+2.

To calculate the difference between in days between two Unix timestamps, use math (a day has 86400 seconds):

```
echo ($unix_timestamp1 - $unix_timestamp2) / 86400;
```

If you've two such dates, you can use `DateTime::diff` as suggested in the comments by Zerocrates. You've create two `DateTime` instances using `DateTime::createFromFormat` and invoke the `DateTime::diff` with two arguments passed, previously created DateTime instances. The returned `DateInterval` instance has a `d` property which contains the difference in days.
The other way would be using the `getTimestamp` method, doing the maths from the previous example.

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php

Comment: Since this is already creating a DateTime object, you might as well use `DateTime::diff` with the current time to get a DateInterval rather than getting the timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

You might find sth here:

[performing datetime related operations in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56568/performing-datetime-related-operations-in-php)

or in php manual there is a lot..

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php