# PHP: E-leave: Calculating two dates using if statement in a while loop

Tags: php, date, if-statement, while-loop

I am trying to calculate the difference between two dates by excluding Saturday and Sunday. The output should be 9 but i got 1 instead.

```
<?php

$date1= mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 20, 2011);
$date2= mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 30, 2011);
$day1= date("D",$date1);
$day2= date("D",$date2);


$i=0;

while ($date1<=$date2)
{


if ($day1 != "Sat" || $day2 !="Sat" || $day1 != "Sun" || $day2 !="Sun")
   {
    $i++;
   }

else
   {
   $i+0;
   }

   $date1=array(date("Y",$date1), date("n",$date1), date("d",$date1)+1);
   }
     $diff=$i;

    echo $diff;

 ?>
```

Comment: you may be interested in reading this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56568/performing-datetime-related-operations-in-php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate business days](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336127/calculate-business-days)

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352712/get-date-range-between-two-dates-excluding-weekends

Answer (score 0):

Seems as if the condition in your if statement is giving the problem.

```
  if ($day1 != "Sat" && $day2 !="Sat" && $day1 != "Sun" && $day2 !="Sun")
 {
  $i++;
 }

 else
 {
  $i+0;
  }
```

Switching || to &&.